# Как произносится "майяская" (цивилизация)?

Tags: словообразование, фонетика

Цивилизация майя оставила нам майяскую культуру. А как произносится это прилагательное?

Comment: Александр Груздев или Дмитрий Полонский, к сожалению не знаю кто именно, в сериале шедшем на телеканале "Культура", озвучил слово как [маjАский] http://kiwi.kz/watch/n13r2gflwxvx/ см. 14:12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Майяский" - совсем уж неблагозвучно звучит. В "динамике" речи такое слово все равно станет звучать как [маj'ск'ий]. В разговорной речи, наверно, это допустимо. А в художественной или научной, на мой взгляд, лучше употребить "цивилизация майя", "культура майя". Хотя поисковик выдает много результов употребления "майяская"

Comment: Спасибо. В научной литературе употребительны "майяская" и "майянская". Второй вариант популярнее, но там непонятно откуда взялся суфикс "-н-".

Comment: Образование или необразование слов само по себе интересно. Например, почему нет в русском языке одного слова для глагола "победить", формы мн.ч. Род. падежа для слова "мечта" ?   :))

Comment: >Второй вариант популярнее, но там непонятно откуда взялся суфикс "-н-".  
  
От соображений благозвучности. Это не суффикс, это протетический звук. Обычно дело для топонимов, этнонимов и этнохоронимов.
Уфа - уфиМец/уфимский, Катманду - катмандуСец, Ява - яваНский... майа - майянский. Сомнений нет.
Насчет признощшения ЙА. Только [Я]. А как еще может?

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучше говорить или "цивилизация майя" или "майянская цивилизация". Поэтому Надюшка получает свой плюс.

Comment: 3. Behemothus, тогда уж интерфикс. Протетический звук бывает только в начале слова. А в искусственном письменном слове, созданном лишь для того, чтобы заменить естественное "майский" (ср. Англия-английский, Австралия-австралийский), интерфикс довольно бессмыслен. Скорей всего он возник под влиянием английского mayan — "принадлежащий, относящийся к майя"

Comment: >Протетический звук бывает только в начале слова.   
  
Вас обманули. )))
 
Да и дело не в этом. Интервикс - это соединительный звук, обычно -  гласная между корнями слов, имеющая вполне конкретное функциональное значение. 
Протеза - неморфемное фонетическое образование, поэтому если уж из жвух зол выбирать, то протезу.

Comment: 6. @behemothus, ладно не буду больше Розенталю верить http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1273/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9  
В то время как по Жеребило, интерфикс - это межморфемная прокладка, играющее в структуре слова соединительную функцию. http://lingvistics_dictionary.academic.ru/1260/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Но спорить на эту тему не намерен, хоть добавляй "н", хоть не добавляй, произношение от этого проще не становится.

Comment: А пизаНский? ЯваНский? БирмаНский? ЛугаНский (от Луга)?  
Англичане там рядом не лежали.
Что касается Розенталя, так я знаю, что в русском сейчас обычно сводят к одному случаю - и сказал, почему я тем не менее выбрал именно этот термин. 
Кстати, там там не сказано, что протезой называется *только* это.

Comment: 8. Если уж выделять, то то, что присоединилось после корня - явАНский, пизАНский и т.д. это и есть интерфиксальная вставка. Например, http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_278809 Когда вчера смотрел про -им- в слове уфимский, даже более конкретный ответ находил, но сейчас найти ту страницу не могу.

Comment: От ЛУга - скорее всего "лужский", или уж "лужицкий". "Луганский" - от названия речки Лугань.А вот отчего такое название - пока не исследовано толком. Наиболее простая версия - от слова"луг".
В отличие от города и реки Лу́га

река в бывш. Петерб. губ., др.-русск. Луга, Жит. Алекс. Невск. 38. От фин. Laukaanjoki – название той же реки (из *lauas, род. п. *laukaan); см. Миккола JSFOu 23, 23, стр. 10; ÄВ 16.

Comment: Ну с Лугой - да, поторопился. Действительно "лужский". Замкнуло на созвучный гидроним. Остальное - в силе.  
По поводу протетический/интерфиксальный, коли уж случай представился.
Это спор чисто терминологический, а посему бессмысленный. Хоть горшком назови. Я исхожу из понятия "протезы" как чего-то дополнительного, к "организму" слова не относящегося. Потому "интерфикс" (в понимании Марка Иза) - частный случай такой протезы. Где-то сталкивался с такой трактовкой - и она мне показалась общепринятой. Даже если ошибаюсь, на суть спора никак не влияет. Хоть горшком назовите, в печку не лезет.

Answer (score 4):

Если предположить, что такое прилагательное есть (а оно есть только у Лопатина), то ударение не должно вызывать вопросов. мАйя - мАйяский.

Вот с его существованием - баальшие сомнения. Аванесов его не знает.

Comment: Меня больше интересует как произносится в данном случае  сочетание -йя- но всё равно спасибо.  
А то, что не знает Аванесов тоже ничего удивительного. Народов много, всех не перечислишь.

Answer (score 3):

Всем спасибо, за высказанные мнения. Так как всё что я хочу сказать по данному вопросу в комментарии не поместится.

Сперва пройдусь по самому прилагательному "майяский" и возможных альтернатив. Понятно, что данное слово употребляется несвободно, но фраза "майя создали письменность майя" ничего кроме улыбки вызвать не может.  Соответственно получается 2 распространённых варианта:

1. МайяНский
2. Майяский

Я склоняюсь ко второму по следующей причине: -н- как его не называй, произношения в данном случае не облегчает и интерфиксной (или по behemothus  протестической) вставкой поэтому не является. Морфологически же объяснить данное написание тоже затруднительно (скорей всего повлияло английское написание, или имя Майа. Именно поэтому Лопатин и привёл слово именно в форме "маяский". Хотя вот через 2 часа опять засомневался. Очень хорошо вписывается корень - "май" суффикс - "-янский", что объясняет почему "Я" под ударением.

Несмотря на моё согласие с орфографическим словарём Лопатина в том как слово пишется, по поводу ударения хочется возразить. Как бы я ни ломал свой язык, но при быстром произношении получается что-то вроде [мАj(иэ)скьj] (иногда даже без первого j), что всё равно на слух корень слова разрушает.

В связи с этим, как мне кажется, ударение действительно предпочтительней сместить, также как это было сделано в фильме телеканала "Культура" (см. ссылку в комментарии к вопросу). В этом случае получается вполне удобопроизносимое [маjАскиj], которое как мне видится, на слух дешифруется  легче, чем вариант с ударением на первом слоге.

Лучший ответ в данном вопросе отдам Надюшке, так как она точнее поняла причину моего затруднения в данном слове.

P.S. Вот через 6 часов опять засомневался, по поводу написания. Очень уж хорошо вписывается усечённый корень - "май" и суффикс - "-янский", что объясняет почему "Я" под ударением...

Comment: >"майя создали письменность майя" 

Не понимаю затруднения. Что мешает переформулировать? Например, "майя создали свою письменность, свой способ счета и много других вещей"...

Comment: 1. Хотя бы потому, что это далеко не всегда удобно, особенно если дело идёт о письменности или языке, которые принято обозначать именно прилагательными.

 Например, "майяские языки насчитывают 28 живых и 3 мёртвых языка", попытка уйти от прилагательного, только усложнит восприятие речи или текста. Также без прилагательного некрасиво будут звучать фразы с перечислением - "египетские, ацтекские, майяские пирамиды". Ну, и ряд других выражений - "майяская игра в мяч" и пр..

Comment: Все равно слово "майяская" выглядит ужасно... Давайте тогда уж говорить "яваский", "бирмаский" и т.д. по списку. И объясните, пожалуйста, почему в Ваших комментариях все время цифра присутствует (от нумерованного списка).

Comment: @gecube Тогда уж "явский", "бирмский". В отличии от слова "майя" названия Явы и Бирмы склоняются, и соединяются основа слова и суффикс -анский.